# Flash as3 spawn an object when click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, block

I am using Flash cc Action script 3.

I need it so that when I click on 'Summonblock' a symbol it will summon Block1, I have no idea what the code may be for this. Even after an 1 hour search... Help as it is for a game 
I am making. Also I need it so it's x position can be anything but it's y has to be a specific value, -350.

Comment: Make sure you assign an instance name to Summonblock and Block1 has a class name. Only then will this be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `Summonblock` an instance name such as `sBlock` and give Block1 a class name such as `Block1`, then you can use this code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

sBlock.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addBlock);

function addBlock(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var b=new Block1;
    b.y=-350;
    addChild(b);
}
```

Comment: @user3406023 The name of a class

Comment: How can I give an object a class name?

Comment: @user3406023 Go to the library, right click the symbol, press properties, export for action script, enter name, enter

Comment: @user3406023 Your welcome. Also, I recommend you take some programming tutorials to learn a bit more about the language ;)